# Downloading files in Kaggle gives - 'failed: Temporary failure in name resolution' error

Tags: github, wget, kaggle

I try to download a script from github on Kaggle  -

```
!rm -rf utils.py
!wget raw.githubusercontent.com/sevenfx/fastai_audio/master/notebooks/utils.py
```

I get this error -

> Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)...
>   failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. wget: unable to resolve
>   host address ‘raw.githubusercontent.com’

Is there any settings in Kaggle  that has to be done or in general whats wrong with this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was [seen before](https://github.com/fastai/course-v3/issues/243#issuecomment-470786371) with a [kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/kernels)

> For anyone in the future who has the same issue in a Kaggle kernel, you need to [turn on internet and gpu](https://forums.fast.ai/t/ive-encountered-this-error-please-help-me-out/39231/3).
>
> On the right side of the kernels window, there should be a settings section:

[image: https://forums.fast.ai/uploads/default/original/3X/2/c/2c37df047ed32f5fa472757186c8ef2309d96158.png]

> You’re gonna want GPU turned on and internet connection turned on.